# Accessing class pointers across several functions

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a problem I've been stuck on for a while trying to make my code more efficient. I've created a Vector class and need to do some basic calculation with it. Using a vector library is out of the question, I need to create my own. 
The problem I have currently is in the final stage of the math. I can enter values for the first and second vector, but upon adding them together I get completely random numbers. I'm posting my header file and my cpp file - any help will be appreciated!!

Vectors.h

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

class Vectors
{
public:
    Vectors(void);
    ~Vectors(void);
    Vectors(double a1, double b1, double c1, double d1)
    {
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
        c = c1;
        d = d1;
    }
    void VectorAdd(Vectors vector1, Vectors vector2);
    void VectorSub();
    void VectorMulti();
    void VectorDiv();
    void VectorDP();
    void VectorCP();
    void setV1(Vectors &vector1);
    void setV2(Vectors &vector2);
private:
     double a;
     double b;
     double c;
     double d;
     double cp;
};
```

Cpp file

```
void Vectors::setV1(Vectors &vector1)
{
    Vectors *Vector1 = new Vectors();
    std::cout << "Enter the values of the first vector please.\n";
    std::cout << "a1: ";
    std::cin >> Vector1 -> a;
    std::cout << "b1: ";
    std::cin >> Vector1 -> b;
    std::cout << "c1: ";
    std::cin >> Vector1 -> c;
    std::cout << "d1: ";
    std::cin >> Vector1 -> d;
    Vector1 = &vector1;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}

void Vectors::setV2(Vectors &vector2)
{
    Vectors *Vector2 = new Vectors();
    std::cout << "Enter the values of the first vector please.\n";
    std::cout << "a1: ";
    std::cin >> Vector2 -> a;
    std::cout << "b1: ";
    std::cin >> Vector2 -> b;
    std::cout << "c1: ";
    std::cin >> Vector2 -> c;
    std::cout << "d1: ";
    std::cin >> Vector2 -> d;
    Vector2 = &vector2;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}

void Vectors::VectorAdd(Vectors vector1, Vectors vector2)
{

    setV1(vector1);
    setV2(vector2);

    Vectors *Vector3 = new Vectors();
    std::cout << "Here is the combination of the two vectors.\n";
    Vector3 -> a = vector1.a + vector2.a;
    std::cout << "a3: " << Vector3 -> a;
    Vector3 -> b = vector1.b + vector2.b;
    std::cout << "\nb3: " << Vector3 -> b;
    Vector3 -> c = vector1.c + vector2.c;
    std::cout << "\nc3: " << Vector3 -> c;
    Vector3 -> d = vector1.d + vector2.d;
    std::cout << "\nd3: " << Vector3 -> d;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector2 = &vector2;
```

You did this backwards. You've overwritten the pointer to a new object you just initialized with a pointer to a completely uninitialized object, that you passed in here. The random data is in the uninitialized object, of course.

You don't need the

```
Vectors *Vector2 = new Vectors();
```

in the first place. Just initialize the `vector2` parameter, directly, from `std::cin`. Ditto for the other function, setV1(), as well. Same thing.

Comment: Thank you! I've always had problems understanding all the pointers, really need to look them over again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is, you are confusing with pointer & reference.

In `void Vectors::setV1(Vectors &vector1)`, you are getting `vector1` as reference. 
Next, you are creating a brand new object `Vectors *Vector1 = new Vectors();`. And then you are continuing to fill `*Vector1`. Till this point, I don't see anything weird. However, this part `Vector1 = &vector1;` totally damages the program. You are now *re-assigning* the pointer `Vector1` with incoming address of `vector1`.

Unless you have some value on the memory as pointed by `vector1` you are not going to have correct results. Infact you are lucky, as you didn't say, your program generated SIGSEGV :)